# water is seeping out from under tub and soaking wood floor

Tags: leaks

Could there be enough condensation under a metal tub to make it have visible water coming from under tub and soaking into floor boards?

Comment: Not likely, assuming you have a regular bathtub I recommend stop using it and check the drain/trap assembly and/or the fill valve assembly.

Comment: Is your tub on an uninsulated, outside wall? This would be the only possible way condensate could be a problem.

Comment: Even on an outside wall (which could cool the tub down) you'd have to ask where that moisture is coming from. Is your house humid enough, and the tub cold enough, for the room air to condense? If not (which seems likely), then you have a leak.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, but probably not. Most likely there is a leak either in the pipes at the valve or shower head or the caulking or grout (if any) has failed. There is sometimes an access hatch on the valve wall (opposite wall-side). This will give you a view of the plumbing. If not look closely on the shower wall for any gaps or cracks that need sealant or caulking.